# Delaying service registration in OSGi. How to do it properly

Tags: java, osgi

When working with declarative services in OSGi, I encountered a special usecase:

Sometimes you want a ds component to register a service as soon a long time operation has completed. Usually this is not a problem since services will be registered after the activate method has finished. However, sometimes it is necessary to open up a thread inside the activate method (in order to avoid the thread from blocking) and register the service once the thread has finished its work, e.g.

```
@Component
public class MyClass implements MyService {

   private ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

@Activate
public void start(final BundleContext context) {
  executor.execute(new Runnable() {

  @Override
  public void run() {

    ...   // doing something for long

     context.registerService(MyService.class, MyClass.this, null);
  }
  });
 }
}
```

We came up with an util class doing exactly that (and covering issues like the component being stopped while the thread is still running etc.). Is there a better way to do such a thing? If not, wouldn't it be convenient to add such an util class to the framework?

Best regards,
Mike

Comment: I think this question is good for the mailinglist for OSGi https://mail.osgi.org/mailman/listinfo lists availabel mailinglists. There are also people subcribed they are members of the specification group

Comment: your example is not compilable ... (registerservice requires an object and properties). You should also not implement MyService

Comment: I changed the example so that it should compile now (sorry). Why shoudn't I implement MyService?

Comment: You shouldn't implement MyService for the reason I tried to explain in my answer below. DS will (by default) immediately register as that service type, irrespective of what your activate method does later on.

Comment: Yes, of course. But it's no problem if I add the service = {} parameter to the component tag, as you mentioned (and as I always do in such cases...) So I don't see a reason why the class shouldn't implement MyService.

Answer (score 1):

DS does not support this use-case directly. Your solution using the `BundleContext` to register the service explicitly is the best available.

You also need to be careful to prevent DS from automatically registering the service as soon as your activate method completes. You should do this by setting the `provide` attribute on the `@Component` annotation to the empty array:

```
@Component(provide = {})
```

Alternatively, don't have the component class directly implement the service interface; use something like an inner class.

Comment: Our solution works just fine. The only drawback is the misleading declaration of the component-tag. Normally you would expect the services provided by the component to be declared within the component tag. I got an angry mail by a colleague the other day claiming I would have removed the correct declaration of the services provided, whenin fact I just had used the "delayed service registration" as I explained above. But that's life ;-)